# How to open the screwed cap of a Mathmos Astro lava lamp?

Tags: home

I have a Mathmos Astro lava lamp bought in 2020 that I need to open to get a piece of debris out. It has a screwed cap that is sealed with some kind of glue. How can I open it without destroying the bottle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a video now that takes you through the whole cleaning process.

https://youtu.be/TON_QcA0QsY

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to put this here because I wasn't able to find any information on how to break the glue sealing. Maybe someone will find this useful some day.

I used a hose clamp, a piece of old bicycle tube for increased friction, and pliers to grip the hose clamp. Didn't use too much force and came off with the first good pull.

[image: Method]

Answer (score 1):

I use a hairdryer on the cap for a couple of minutes which loosens the glue up.